# Install Directory Structure

Tags: git, directory-structure

I have a git repository that has a lot of ignored  directories in it. However, when someone new downloads the repository, I want them to have the directory structure just not the files within it.

For example, my structure is

- Data

  - Folder1
  - ...
  - Folder20

And I currently have a `.gitignore` with `!.gitignore` in Data. Is the best to create the structure to have a script in my repository that installs it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Provide a script in your repository, like `makedirs.sh` and instruct the user to run that script after checking out the repository, in the README file.  The script should take care to create the necessary structure.
- Stop ignoring these directories, create a dummy file with a name like `.empty` or `.placeholder` or `.donotremoveme` etc, and add them all — this will ensure the directory structure is kept and checked out because the files are.

Answer (score 0):

Git can't track empty directory unless it is a gitlink

Please do "touch .fake; i.e dot.fake" an ensure that you don't put this name in .gitignore

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, you need to put a file into the directory in order for git to track it. But instead of ".fake", why not put a README file in there with a bit of actual documentation about what kinds of files you expect users to create inside the directory. (Since you need to put a file in there, may as well use it for something!)